# XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to XMLParserConfiguration

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Getting this error when building my Android Project in Android Studio. Have tried the two options suggested but of no avail.

```
class org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to class org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration (org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @7b2340a9; org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @2157f7ea)
class org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to class org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration (org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @7b2340a9; org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @2157f7ea)
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

'

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this error goes away after doing an Invalidate and restart in Android Studio.